Godot closes automaticaly when reopen a specific scene
I open the project and work in the main scene and all is ok. Them I open other scenes, or just already opened scenes and work in them normally. Then I click again in the already opened main scene and the engine closes automatically withiout any advice or popup. I can still work in the game but it is really annoying. I'm new to Godot so I don't know yet where to look for soloution to this.
This is the tscn file as txt:
[gd_scene load_steps=25 format=3 uid="uid://bsf2o7tbx7jf4"]

[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://ctpj7vutf8x8t" path="res://Player/Player.tscn" id="1_ucvfk"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://celueydse0ha7" path="res://Assets/platform_big.tscn" id="2_km684"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/Camera2D.gd" id="4_1eqss"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://bvcblmp3arcru" path="res://Assets/platform_small.tscn" id="4_s304j"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://c5lm07yh2k1od" path="res://Assets/BackGround.tscn" id="5_f58ky"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/Eraser.gd" id="5_mtntl"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/DieZone.gd" id="7_8lb55"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://can3i0w42b5j3" path="res://Assets/ItemGenerator.tscn" id="7_8tphp"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://c6flqyyver72a" path="res://Assets/generador.tscn" id="8_0jbxy"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://e6me4r5mvkna" path="res://Assets/sparks_up.tscn" id="9_kegdm"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://e0jucg1w6dji" path="res://Assets/puntaje.tscn" id="9_qlkeu"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/sparks_up.gd" id="10_yihnu"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://dbpqyfxsyfy72" path="res://Assets/Items/Beef.tscn" id="13_xd71t"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://weueemnh2v05" path="res://Assets/Items/Celula.tscn" id="14_kf4ss"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://5c6li8r0f757" path="res://Assets/Items/Leg.tscn" id="15_r6vdc"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://bvcvsjon3p1ji" path="res://Assets/Items/Lengua.tscn" id="16_iye50"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/gameTimer.gd" id="17_kjjac"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://cgiqvhojh0520" path="res://Player/Player_Musc.tscn" id="18_kdfe2"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://bxuotvu4672qp" path="res://Assets/shootGenerator.tscn" id="19_4e5r7"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://dvq62k518ssgb" path="res://Assets/fireball.tscn" id="20_078fd"]

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_slslj"]
size = Vector2(2151, 165.5)

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_fe4jy"]
size = Vector2(416.512, 20)

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_ay8dg"]
size = Vector2(229.466, 20)

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_c845b"]
size = Vector2(227, 2912)

[node name="MainLevel" type="Node2D"]

[node name="Platform_big" parent="." instance=ExtResource("2_km684")]
position = Vector2(1158, 989)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="platform_small" parent="." instance=ExtResource("4_s304j")]
position = Vector2(2737, 962)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="platform_small2" parent="." instance=ExtResource("4_s304j")]
position = Vector2(3770, 962)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="platform_small3" parent="." instance=ExtResource("4_s304j")]
position = Vector2(4796, 962)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="ParallaxBackground" parent="." instance=ExtResource("5_f58ky")]

[node name="Player" parent="." instance=ExtResource("1_ucvfk")]
z_index = 2
z_as_relative = false
y_sort_enabled = true
position = Vector2(441, 796)
scale = Vector2(0.376, 0.376)
SPEED = 400.0
gravity = 3500

[node name="Beef" parent="." instance=ExtResource("13_xd71t")]
position = Vector2(865, 796)

[node name="Celula" parent="." instance=ExtResource("14_kf4ss")]
position = Vector2(1060, 823)

[node name="Leg" parent="." instance=ExtResource("15_r6vdc")]
position = Vector2(1264, 823)

[node name="Lengua" parent="." instance=ExtResource("16_iye50")]
position = Vector2(1596, 819)

[node name="gameTimer" type="Timer" parent="."]
unique_name_in_owner = true
one_shot = true
script = ExtResource("17_kjjac")

[node name="Player2" parent="." instance=ExtResource("18_kdfe2")]
visible = false
position = Vector2(611, 801)
scale = Vector2(0.395, 0.395)

[node name="Camera2D" type="Camera2D" parent="." node_paths=PackedStringArray("player")]
show_behind_parent = true
top_level = true
z_index = 3
position = Vector2(960, 540)
scale = Vector2(0.999998, 0.999998)
zoom = Vector2(0.225, 0.225)
script = ExtResource("4_1eqss")
player = NodePath("../Player")

[node name="Limits" type="Node2D" parent="Camera2D"]
position = Vector2(-961, -541)

[node name="LimitUp" type="StaticBody2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(36, -306)

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/LimitUp"]
position = Vector2(995, -158)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_slslj")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="DieZone" type="Area2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(970, 1547)
script = ExtResource("7_8lb55")

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone"]
position = Vector2(300, 0)
scale = Vector2(7.025, 7.025)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_fe4jy")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="DieZone2" type="Area2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(-102, 0)
script = ExtResource("7_8lb55")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone2"]
position = Vector2(-6.00109, 507)
rotation = 1.57079
scale = Vector2(7.025, 7.025)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_ay8dg")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="Eraser" type="Area2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(-2203, 8)
script = ExtResource("5_mtntl")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/Eraser"]
position = Vector2(27, 465)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_c845b")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="PlatGenerador" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("8_0jbxy")]
position = Vector2(3677, -249)
timeMax = 5.0

[node name="PlatGenerador2" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("8_0jbxy")]
position = Vector2(3244, 94)
timeMax = 10.0
timeMin = 3.0

[node name="PlatGenerador3" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("8_0jbxy")]
position = Vector2(2891, 418)
timeMax = 6.0
timeMin = 2.0

[node name="ItemGenerator" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("7_8tphp")]
position = Vector2(3813, -370)
timeMax = 10.0
timeMin = 5.0

[node name="ItemGenerator2" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("7_8tphp")]
position = Vector2(3441, -62)
timeMax = 3.0
timeMin = 5.0

[node name="ItemGenerator3" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("7_8tphp")]
position = Vector2(3017, 270)
timeMax = 2.0
timeMin = 3.0

[node name="Porcentaje" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("9_qlkeu")]
offset_left = 819.0
offset_top = -436.0
offset_right = 859.0
offset_bottom = -379.0

[node name="SparksUp" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("9_kegdm")]
position = Vector2(954, 434)
emitting = false
script = ExtResource("10_yihnu")

[node name="MarkPosScore" type="Marker2D" parent="Camera2D"]
position = Vector2(1337, -401)

[node name="ShootGenerator" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("19_4e5r7")]
position = Vector2(1245, 365.001)
timeMax = 0.5
timeMin = 0.2

[node name="Fireball" parent="Camera2D" node_paths=PackedStringArray("firetgt") instance=ExtResource("20_078fd")]
position = Vector2(1190, 243)
pointsValue = 50.0
firetgt = NodePath("../firetgt")

[node name="firetgt" type="Marker2D" parent="Camera2D"]
position = Vector2(401.001, -245)

[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Player" method="_on_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/PlatGenerador" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/PlatGenerador2" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/PlatGenerador3" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ItemGenerator" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ItemGenerator2" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ItemGenerator3" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ShootGenerator" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="timeout" from="gameTimer" to="Player" method="_on_game_timer_timeout"]
[connection signal="body_entered" from="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone" to="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone" method="_on_body_entered"]
[connection signal="body_entered" from="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone2" to="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone2" method="_on_body_entered"]
[connection signal="body_entered" from="Camera2D/Limits/Eraser" to="Camera2D/Limits/Eraser" method="_on_body_entered"]


I don't know what to try or look. I expect to work normally without the engine closing all the time.

This seems to be a running problem with Godot 4.

Thanks for the link!!! I checked and tryed the solutons as it says there. Unfortunately didn't work

Godot has systems in place to inform you about the source of the issue. when that doesn't work, you need to check the subresources of your scene one by one.

Open all of the subresources listed at the top of your tscn file. see if the scenes work individually.
Replace all of your subresource paths with dummy resources in your scene. Make sure no referenced scripts are "tool" scripts.
Resource your subresources one by one.


Thanks for the guide on finding the problem!! I remove the resources and find the character tscn is causing the issue. I need to review all the character scene til find the problem... I use the Skeleton2DModificationstack, and it causes A LOT of errors and seems to be a bug. So I'll check the character, hope I can fix it!

Managing resources is always a trick. You need to take extra care to import them cleanly and not goober them somehow afterwards. Sometimes the resource data in ~/.import stops matching the resources in your source directory.

I did what @TheNegative said and it solved a lot. I worked well in some tscn scenes, and in others I didn't try it (the scene is really complex). But it seems opening the project in Godot 4.3 overrides the issue and a lot of other errors reported about the skeleton2DModificationStack. Always remember doing a backup befor opening the project in a new software version.
